# How do I make SMPTE colour bars using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, colors

I want to make this image
[image]

using Batch, but I'm not sure how- I know how to echo in batch, but I don't know what to echo, how to get the right colours and what the size of the windows should be. Should the size be:

```
mode con:cols=37 lines=22
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @Dai I am making it into a virus- not a real one- one to prank someone and this will part of the special effects. Don't judge me.

Comment: On Windows 10 you could use [Ansi escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) to create this picture

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `cecho.exe` which should work from WinXP and above.

Comment: @SteveFest I am not sure what you mean, as I get this message:

'cecho.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

So, I downloaded it from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files

and do I put it into the System32 folder?

Comment: Yes you do. Please only put the `.exe` file in System32

Comment: OK, thanks @SteveFest

Comment: @cybergodfather666 Note: On your victim's system, you will need `cecho.exe` in System32 folder/ or your batch file folder/ a folder in path variable. I recommend you to copy `cecho.exe` with your batch file to your victim's PC.

Comment: But please can you give me the code on what to put into my batch code? As I'm a beginner and I'm not sure what the mode would be and how to get the bars @SteveFest

Comment: First off: Do `cecho.exe /?` - It tells your everything. This command's ability is too much to be fit in the comment.

Comment: @SteveFest thats fine, but is the code to get it too much? If so, can you give it in blocks?

Comment: @cybergodfather666 I'm writing the actual code. My estimation: generating this picture + `mode` command would only take 30 ~ 50 lines.

Comment: @cybergodfather666 or if you use `for` loop, this could be shortened to ~10 - 20 lines

Comment: OK, thanks @SteveFest and please upload it when finished. Thank You!

Comment: @cybergodfather666 and please note Stack Overflow is not a forum, nor a write-code-for-me site.

Comment: @SteveFest oh, ok

Comment: @cybergodfather666 Also, have you read stackoverflow.com/help? This site is a "Don't panic" manual for Stack Overflow

Comment: @SteveFest right. Thanks for uploading the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cecho.exe` can do what you need.

```
mode con:cols=70 lines=20
for /l %%G in (1,1,10) do (
     cecho.exe {07}aaaaaaaaa{#}{06}aaaaaaaaaa{#}{0B}aaaaaaaaaa{#}{0A}aaaaaaaaaaa{0D}aaaaaaaaaa{#}{04}aaaaaaaaaa{#}{01}aaaaaaaaa{#}{\n}
)

for /l %%G in (1,1,2) do (
     cecho.exe {01}aaaaaaaaa{#}          {0D}aaaaaaaaaa{#}           {0B}aaaaaaaaaa{#}          {07}aaaaaaaaa{#}{\n}
)

 for /l %%G in (1,1,3) do (
     cecho.exe {01}aaaaaaaaa{#}{0F}aaaaaaaaaa{#}{05}aaaaaaaaaa{#}                                        {\n}
)
```

You can change the `a`'s to whatever character you like - just note the codepage issue. You may want to change codepage(`chcp`) to `65000`/`65001` for Unicode in UTF-7 and UTF-8. Codepage `437`(OEM is also a good option)

- `mode` command changes the console size
- The first `for /l` loop runs the command in the brackets 10 times
- The second `for /l` loop runs the command in the brackets 2 times
- The third `for /l` loop runs the command in the brackets 3 times
- `cecho` echoes out colored text.

  - `{nn}` is the color code, followed by the text
  - `{#}` resets to the original console color
  - `{\n}` creates a new line
  - When you want to `cecho` a `{`, make sure you write `{{`.

Comment: This is very helpful and useful @stevefest thanks! I have ticked it just so you know, and THANKS!